# How to mount stackable filesystem wrapfs on /

Tags: filesystems, mount

I am trying to mount wrapfs on top of `/` in order to intercept all file access on a CentOS 7.4 running on VirtualBox. Simply running 
`mount -t wrapfs / /`
doesn't do the job and nothing goes through wrapfs.

An [email chain](http://www.fsl.cs.sunysb.edu/pipermail/wrapfs/2015-October/000117.html) suggests using `pivot_root`. Here is my unsuccessful attempt:

```
# df -T
Filesystem              Type      1K-blocks      Used  Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root xfs        27245572  10640700   16604872  40% /
devtmpfs                devtmpfs    1925092         0    1925092   0% /dev
tmpfs                   tmpfs       1940872         0    1940872   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                   tmpfs       1940872      8944    1931928   1% /run
tmpfs                   tmpfs       1940872         0    1940872   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1               xfs         1038336    181844     856492  18% /boot
VB-share                vboxsf   1942808572 658135288 1284673284  34% /media/sf_VB-share
tmpfs                   tmpfs        388176        24     388152   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sr1                iso9660       57064     57064          0 100% /run/media/bahram/VBox_GAs_5.2.26

# mkdir /newroot
# mkdir /oldroot
# mount /dev/mapper/centos-root /newroot
# mount -t wrapfs /newroot /newroot
# mount --make-rprivate /
# pivot_root /newroot/ /newroot/oldroot/
```

Result:

- In the current terminal all file access goes through wrapfs.
- Running `# mount` will result: `mount: failed to read mtab: No such file or directory`.
- I cannot open any new terminals!

Next, I tried a similar process with `unshare -m`

```
mkdir /newroot
mkdir /oldroot
mount /dev/mapper/centos-root /newroot
mount -t wrapfs /newroot /newroot
unshare -m 
pivot_root /newroot/ /newroot/oldroot/
exec chroot .
```

Result:

Only the current terminal activities goes through wrapfs.
Running `# mount` will result:
`mount: failed to read mtab: No such file or directory`.

Question:

What is the right way of mounting wrapfs on top of `/` so every file access goes through wrapfs?